# Obtain referer in Java SOAP webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I feel like this should be straight forward. We are implementing a Java webservice using SOAP in Eclipse. We want to know who is calling the webservice. I would have though I could get the referer from the header somehow but am at a loss as to how to do it. We are using Axis 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copied from [TechNick](http://thetechnick.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/get-client-ip-in-axis2.html) you can leverage axis2 for this.  The fact you're using Eclipse is largely irrelevant, the code below should work fine.

```
//Import statement to import MessageContext class
import org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext;

/*
* This method gets the client IP address using axis2 MessageContext 
*
* @return Client IP : String
*/
private String getClientIP () {

      return (String)(MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext()).getProperty(MessageContext.REMOTE_ADDR);

}
```